# Laravel named route - form routes to wrong resource route

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-blade

routes.php

```
/**
 *
 * Login Functionality
 * 
 */

Route::get('login', 'SessionsController@create');
Route::get('logout', 'SessionsController@destroy');
Route::resource('sessions', 'SessionsController');

/**
 *
 * Admin Routes
 * 
 */

Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function()
{
    Route::resource('tests', 'Admin\TestController');
});
```

php artisan routes

```
+--------+-----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+----------------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
| Domain | URI                                           | Name                          | Action                                 | Before Filters | After Filters |
+--------+-----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+----------------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
|        | GET /                                         |                               | Closure                                |                |               |
|        | GET login                                     |                               | SessionsController@create              |                |               |
|        | GET logout                                    |                               | SessionsController@destroy             |                |               |
|        | GET sessions                                  | sessions.index                | SessionsController@index               |                |               |
|        | GET sessions/create                           | sessions.create               | SessionsController@create              |                |               |
|        | POST sessions                                 | sessions.store                | SessionsController@store               |                |               |
|        | GET sessions/{sessions}                       | sessions.show                 | SessionsController@show                |                |               |
|        | GET sessions/{sessions}/edit                  | sessions.edit                 | SessionsController@edit                |                |               |
|        | PUT sessions/{sessions}                       | sessions.update               | SessionsController@update              |                |               |
|        | PATCH sessions/{sessions}                     |                               | SessionsController@update              |                |               |
|        | DELETE sessions/{sessions}                    | sessions.destroy              | SessionsController@destroy             |                |               |
|        | GET admin/tests                               | admin.tests.index             | Admin\TestController@index             |                |               |
|        | GET admin/tests/create                        | admin.tests.create            | Admin\TestController@create            |                |               |
|        | POST admin/tests                              | admin.tests.store             | Admin\TestController@store             |                |               |

...
```

sessions/create.blade.php

```
{{ Form::open(
    array(
        'route'  => array('sessions.store'),
        'role'   => 'form',
        'class'  => 'form-horizontal'
    )
) }}
```

output when visiting `http://localhost/login`

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost/admin/tests" accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form" class="form-horizontal"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="yQZH861VbytYsA8bBboYv5YexVInP33LdxmVHtq2">
    <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="yQZH861VbytYsA8bBboYv5YexVInP33LdxmVHtq2">
```

For some reason, `'route'  => array('sessions.store'),` is pointing to the route `'route'  => array('admin.tests.store'),`.

Any idea what is going on or how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

I"m not sure why you're seeing the behavior you're seeing, but if you're just sending them to the `sessions.store` route, it should look like

`'route' => 'sessions.store'` instead of `'route' => array('sessions.store')`

The array lets you pass in route parameters, but without the parameters, I'm not sure what's happening.

http://laravel.com/docs/html